# Locks VS Memory Barriers

Tags: multithreading, memory, synchronization, locks, memory-barriers

When can locks be avoided by using memory barriers ? Like in this case : [Consumer-Producer-Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Without_semaphores_or_monitors) ( The last implementation is using memory barrier and rest all are using locks or semaphores.)

Is it better to use memory barrier in such cases than locks? If yes, Why?

What are the most common situations where locks can be avoided using memory barriers ?

Comment: You already know the answer, if a memory barrier would be always better then there wouldn't be any point in a locking primitive..  Google "livelock and starvation" to learn more.

Comment: @Hans Passant Needed to know the scenarios when memory barrier use would be encouraged. Can you throw some light on this ?

Comment: Yes @Hans, locks cannot be avoided in all cases. And that is why adisticated asked the question in the first place. I guess he wants to know  about the situations where unnecessary locks can be avoided.

Comment: @adisticated, You should also see this http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2007/02/19/please-dont-rely-on-memory-barriers-for-synchronization/

Answer (score -1):

A mutex needs to perform a memory barrier by definition. If a mutex didn't include a memory barrier, operations on the data to which it was providing exclusive access could be reordered outside of the critical region.

Separately, mutexes implementations generally need to perform a memory barrier themselves else the mutex itself could get reordered.

In other words, the implementation of a mutex includes a memory barrier in order to perform the atomic locking necessary to enforce mutual exclusion, but even if it did not need to, a mutex would include a memory barrier else it wouldn't be very useful.

**Conclusion**: If you don't want your code to break, use locks everywhere even where memory barriers are required.

```
inline void mb_()
{
    mutex_t mtx;
    mutex_init(&mtx);
    mutex_lock(&mtx);
    mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

If you are aiming for performance, you might require advanced techniques.

Comment: Would locks be of a little more overhead than mere use of memory barriers?

Comment: the mutex internally call mem_fence kind of instruction, and this kind of code block has a very small overhead. There is a small chance that  any of thread will wait on locks.